# Integers from MySQL are converted to strings by Eloquent. How to fix this on a Homestead box?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, homestead

Most responses mention to enable mysqlnd.

The point is that Homestead comes with mysqlnd enabled, but the problem is still there.

Can somebody points us out how to solve this issue with a fresh Homestead installation?

It just horrible to programmatically casts all int and float values.

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen this behavior with `'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]` set in mysql settings in `/config/database.php`.  Can you confirm this is not set?

Comment: This is what I have (default in Laravel 8):
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA')
            ]) : [],